# Prometheus and Azure WebApps: How to monitor multiple instances with prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have an application that has two instances running and each request runs on a different machine.

I am monitoring an event with a counter in my application and each instance runs it's own counter using prometheus-net. It would be great if prometheus-net was using a caching mechanism other that in-memory, maybe a redis, so whenever prometheus scrap /metrics, it gets the same data each time.

Unfortunately, each scrap request from prometheus runs on a different machine and it's like I have two counters.

I need a way to tell to prometheus to scrap two urls and I will find a way to combine them.

Unfortunately, the way to access directly the web app instance is by using parameters.

The urls looks like that:

```
https://example.com/metrics?instance=dba246887a8c3c07e1a9cc331d7372c43937e6acd56073246ffdf0e95597480c
https://example.com/metrics?instance=be007691832f4002a86cf0148768a3b039304e9b1fa7ae91a032b0beddc152b2
```

That way I cannot use the following code since I cannot add full url here.

```
 static_configs:
      - targets: ['example.com']
```

I tried the following but it didn't created two 'instances' at the label `instance`

```
- job_name: 'example'
    scrape_interval: 30s
    params:
      -instance: ['372c43937e6acd56073246ffdf0e95597480cdba24688cc331d77a8c3c07e1a9','be007691832f4002a86cf0148768a3b039304e9b1fa7ae91a032b0beddc152b2']
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['example.com']
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: https
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this similarly to how it's done in [blackbox_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter#prometheus-configuration): list identifying information of your targets in the `target` block, and then use relabeling to replace scraping address with address of your actual exporter and to place targets into parameters of scraping request.

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'myjob'
    static_configs:
      - targets:  # Targets to probe using parameters
        - 372c43937e6acd56073246ffdf0e95597480cdba24688cc331d77a8c3c07e1a9   
        - be007691832f4002a86cf0148768a3b039304e9b1fa7ae91a032b0beddc152b2
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_instance
      - source_labels: [__param_instance]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: example.com  # The exporter's real address
```

please notice here: `__param_instance` is a label that will be used during scraping as URL parameter with name `instance`.

Here replacement config does:

1. puts ids from target list into parameter `instance`,
2. puts content of that parameter into final label `instance` (otherwise content of `__address__` will be used),
3. puts address of actual target into label `__address__` to be used bu scraping.